# get selected listview item row from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a listview that is bound to a database:

```
//C# code
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet1.ProductDataTable pTable = new ProductTableAdapter().GetDataByCategory();

        productListview.DataSource = pTable.Rows;
        productListview.DataBind();
    }
```

When I click on a linkbutton I want to get all columns from that chosen databaserow.

```
    //ASP.NET
    <asp:Listview ID="productListview" runat="server" GroupItemCount="3">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table runat="server">
            <tr>
              <th colspan="3">PRODUCTS LIST</th>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server" id="groupPlaceholder" />
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <GroupTemplate>
      <tr>
        <td runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
      </tr>
    </GroupTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
                <td>
                    <img src='<%# Eval("PicURL") %>' width="150" height="150"/><br />
                    <asp:LinkButton 
                        ID="chosenLinkButton" runat="server" 
                        CommandName="AddProduct"
                        CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>' 
                        Text='<%#Eval("ProductName") %>'><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Price") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Size") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SalesQuantity") %>'></asp:Label> 
                </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Listview>
```

After this I want to take the row values and put them in a class that is called "cartItems"
where I have properties like Price, Name, description, like this:

```
private string ProductName;
    public string _ProductName
    {
        get { return ProductName; }
        set
        {
            ProductName = value;
        }
    }
```

UPDATED below!
this doesent work. it doesent fetch the price from the database, what am I doing wrong?

```
        protected void productListview_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //Made a adapter to database cause I thought I could get the selected talbe colums from here...
        DataSet1.ProductDataTable productTable = new ProductTableAdapter().GetDataByCategory();

        if (e.CommandName == "AddProduct")
        {
            //create a cartItem instance that contains ProductName, UnitPrice, type & decription
            var currentPrimaryKey = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            CartItem chosenItem = new CartItem();
            chosenItem.UnitPrice = (decimal)productTable.Columns.IndexOf("Price");
                //how can I add the price from the database here? 

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wire up your code to the ItemCommand event on the ListView

Use code for your link similar to below;

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>'
                                    CommandName="Select" > <%# Convert.ToString(Eval("Description")) %></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: I have updated my code now, can you tell me whats wrong? Do u need more code to debug? Is there a simple way of getting the price from the database and set it to my CartItem instance? Thaks alot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

### THE SOLOUTION

```
 foreach (DataSet1.ProductRow item in pTable.Rows)
            {
                //if the current item in the table is matching the item that is selected by the user
                if (item.ID == Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)) 
                {
                    //then assign values to a created instance of a cartItem (a class that I have)
                    CartItem currentItem = new CartItem();
                    currentItem.UnitPrice = item.Price;  
                }
            }
```

**Conclution:**
To convert an abject into a integer by useing the Convert.ToInt32() method.